# iOS bluetooth talk to bluetooth device

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I am developing an iOS app that uses bluetooth to connect to my self made device and send simple text commands. Device's bluetooth is 2.1 version (profiles like SPP, HID, HDP supported, but LE not supported). Is there any way that my iPhone (4s and later) could talk to this device(MFI needed?)? Or I have to change my device bluetooth to 4.0 version with low energy in it that iPhones support?

Comment: You will need a BLE device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then there really is no chance to talk to the device without BLE?

Comment: Possibly via a jailbreak.  I haven't ever looked into that